# Selecting template based on content of a string argument

Tags: c++, boost, std

I've come across a problem using `boost::property_tree` that probably has more generic applications. My goal was to create a loader function that is capable of choosing the correct loader depending on the file extension. My solution is to use consecutive `if else-if` statements:

```cpp
auto extension = input_filename.extension().string();
if(iequals(extension, ".json"))      pt::read_json(input_filename.string(), tree);
else if(iequals(extension, ".info")) pt::read_info(input_filename.string(), tree);
else if(iequals(extension, ".xml"))  pt::read_xml(input_filename.string(), tree);
else if(iequals(extension, ".ini"))  pt::read_ini(input_filename.string(), tree);
else   ... // unknown file type
```

I think there should be a better solution than this. If I recall python where you can do something like `map<extension, function>[extension](input_filename.string(), tree)` it inspired me to the following. The idea was to use a map to create the relationship between the extension string and the function:

```cpp
using loader_fct = void(*)(const std::string &, pt::ptree &, const std::locale &);
using loader_table = std::map<std::string, loader_fct>;

const loader_table load_funct{
        {".json", &pt::read_json},
        {".ini",  &pt::read_ini},
        {".info", &pt::read_info},
//      {".xml",  &pt::read_xml}
};
```

The first problem was that apparently not all of the loader functions(-templates) had the same signature, therefore we cannot use xml. Furthermore we have to define all template arguments, then we can use it in the following way:

```
auto extension = boost::to_lower_copy(input_filename.extension().string());
auto loader = load_funct.find(extension);
loader->second(input_filename.string(), tree, std::locale());
```

I was able to address the issue with the differing function signatures with the help of some templates, which allow us to simplify a little bit more:

```
template<typename Ptree>
void read_json(const std::string & s, Ptree & t) { pt::read_json(s, t); }

template<typename Ptree>
void read_ini(const std::string & s, Ptree & t) { pt::read_ini(s, t); }

template<typename Ptree>
void read_info(const std::string & s, Ptree & t) { pt::read_info(s, t); }

template<typename Ptree>
void read_xml(const std::string & s, Ptree & t) { pt::read_xml(s, t); }

using loader_table = std::map<std::string, void(*)(const std::string &, pt::ptree &)>;
loader_table load_funct{
        {".json", &read_json},
        {".ini",  &read_ini},
        {".info", &read_info},
        {".xml",  &read_xml}
};
auto extension = boost::to_lower_copy(input_filename.extension().string());
if(load_funct.count(extension))
{
        load_funct[extension](input_filename.string(), tree);
}
```

My basic question:

**Are there better ways to do this? Or other ideas?**

The last solution made me think whether there is a possibility to do the selection of the correct loader already in the template?

Comment: You can skip the function definitions by using a lambda: `{".json", [](auto s, auto t) { read_json(s, t); }}`. Honestly, your if-else solution seems alright. Maybe you could use a `to_extension_enum` (As a `std::map<std::string, extension_enum_t>`) and then a `switch`.

Comment: @Artyer, Your hint with the lambda was great! I've used it a number of times already. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll gladly accept it.